# PHPize Compiling Mongo Driver for Ubuntu API Options Not Matching

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running into a problem getting a valid mongo driver compiled for the API version of PHP that I'm running.  Using php - v

PHP 5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

What is happening is that even when I use what I think is the **correct** phpize it is still configuring the build for an **older** API version.

When I run /usr/bin/phpize -v here is what I get:
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212

BUT when I try to use the compiled version of the mongo driver I get this warning message:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226

Here is the whereis php output:

php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5.6 /etc/php /usr/lib/php /usr/share/php5.6-mysql /usr/share/php5.6-common /usr/share/php5.6-xml /usr/share/php5.6-curl /usr/share/php5.6-mcrypt /usr/share/php5.6-intl /usr/share/php /usr/share/php5.6-readline /usr/share/php5.6-gd /usr/share/php5.6-opcache /usr/share/php5.6-json /usr/share/php5.6-mbstring /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

Can someone please give me step by step instructions on how to properly compile the Mongo driver on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what command you are exactly using, but you should be fine running `pecl install` on ubuntu.

So to install this official PHP driver for mongo: https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb just run:

```
pecl install mongodb
```

and you should be good to go. Maybe it tells you that some libs are missing, but you can use `apt-get install` to install them afterwards.

You can read more about the driver [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/)

If pecl command is not found, install it using

```
apt-get install php-pear
```

Comment: Yes I've already done that and it tells me that I have the latest mongo drive installed:    sudo pecl install mongodb
pecl/mongodb is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.8

Comment: And as soon as I add the installed mongo driver to my php.ini file /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini I get the " Unable to initialize module " error message

Comment: Did you add `extension=mongo.so` to your /etc/php5/mods-available/mongodb.ini ? What's the issue exactly?

Comment: Did you get an error when completing the `pecl install`?

Comment: The first time I did the install no but since it is ALREADY installed I get this:  sudo pecl install mongodb
pecl/mongodb is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.8
install failed

Comment: And No Stefan I didn't add the mongo.so driver to the mongodb.ini file.  I added it to my PHP-CLI ini file and I got the error message I outlined in my original message:  Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20121212 PHP compiled with module API=20131226